# Querying Data in a Table [mySQL]

Tags: mysql

I've got a table with 4 instructors including their BDates and salaries. How can I find which instructor has the least salary out of the 4?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(DEPTNO CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
DEPTNAME VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
LOCATION CHAR(16) DEFAULT 'KUWAIT',
BUDGET NUMERIC(8,2));
CREATE TABLE INSTRUCTOR
(ID CHAR(5),
NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
DEPTNO CHAR(3),
SALARY NUMERIC(8,2),
GENDER CHAR(1) DEFAULT '?',
BDATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY PK_INST(ID),
FOREIGN KEY FK_INST_DEPT (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (DEPTNO));
```

Instructor gave us a hint that goes something like this

```
select name from A as instructor, B as instructor
```

then do something like

```
A.salary > B.salary
```

that's as much as I know

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY salaries ASC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Please show your database schema and what have you tried.

Comment: added more info

Answer (score -2):

SELECT MIN(SALARY) AS 'Minimum salary'
FROM *table name*